# Which form of god is referred to as Dhanakapuri Dakurnath in Hinduism?

Tags: shiva, krishna, gods, name

I was curious about the origin of the name Dakurnath, specifically. It is my priest's given name after my birth and initiation to a Hindu family. I googled it and found [google book](https://books.google.com/books?id=d1u0Di4_L30C&pg=PT26&lpg=PT26&dq=Dhanakapuri%20Dakurnath&source=bl&ots=dDGTDcAO4H&sig=ACfU3U04ulGBN4fWjKsqkWvdiIEP51-Nng&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjKnrbFm8nqAhUDKawKHXodBEUQ6AEwAHoECAEQAQ#v=onepage&q=Dhanakapuri%20Dakurnath&f=false) like 'Dhanakapuri Dakurnath' mentioned next to 'Shri Krishna of Dwarka'.